# Trying run working Laravel project on my PC via XAMPP

Tags: php, laravel, xampp

I have a whole project with database, everything is working here.

[Project with database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgztS.png)

I would like to run website so I can see changes I have made. 
Im using XAMPP. My configs for VirtualHost [hosts and http-vghosts.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9y0Th.png)

I have tried this https://youtu.be/iXYCnYRalaw?t=2m13s ->> from [2:13] to [4:22]
using XAMPP, but still cant run it.

Can you give me any advice or steps how to make website run on my PC? [ofcourse just for me (VirtualHost)].

Editor using: Atom

[My PC spec](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwvT1.png)

Comment: pictures and links to videos are not how you ask a question here I suggest reading [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question). Also, be sure to take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Im sorry. I will fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If running laravel appliation inside XAMPP htdocs folder is really necessary, then could you provide some kind of error, simply telling "it doesn't work" doesn't help at all.

One thing you can try is to open command prompt inside laravel folder and run

```
php artisan serve
```

This will open local server that runs current project in:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000
```

Also, checking laravel minimum requirements is something you should check out. 5.5 requires PHP 7 and you didnt tell what XAMPP version you are running.